# A problem of implicit conversions in scala 2.8

Tags: scala, scala-2.8, implicit-conversion

I want to write a implicit conversion of Tuple2[A,B] to Seq[C] where C is super type of both A and B.
My first try as following:

```
implicit def t2seq[A,B,C](t: (A,B))(implicit env: (A,B) <:< (C,C)): Seq[C] = {
    val (a,b) = env(t)
    Seq(a,b)
}
```

But it doesn't work:

```
scala> (1,2): Seq[Int]
<console>:7: error: type mismatch;
 found   : (Int, Int)
 required: Seq[Int]
       (1,2): Seq[Int]
       ^
```

While this one works:

```
class Tuple2W[A,B](t: (A,B)) {
    def toSeq[C](implicit env: (A,B) <:< (C,C)): Seq[C] = {
        val (a,b) = env(t)
        Seq(a,b)
    }
}
implicit def t2tw[A,B](t: (A,B)): Tuple2W[A,B] = new Tuple2W(t)
```

Use case:

```
scala> (1,2).toSeq
res0: Seq[Int] = List(1, 2)
```

I have no idea why the first solution didn't work as expected.
**Scala version 2.8.0.r22634-b20100728020027 (Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM, Java 1.6.0_20).**

Comment: I think '<:<' parameters are usually called 'ev' (short for 'evidence'), not env.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You only need to use `<:<` if the parameters to be restricted are already bound in the surrounding scope (as they are in your second try), so in your case

```
implicit def t2seq[A <: C,B <: C,C](t: (A,B)) = Seq(t._1, t._2)
```

is sufficient.

I would guess that your first try did not work as it is too complex for the type inferencer.